# Can i find out if the ordinary object pointer is compressed in my current jdk

Tags: java, jvm

I have the below version of jdk currently running:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Is there way to verify if oop compression is supported by this jdk? I am still learning, so please excuse if this sounds very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JVM output(via `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`) in order to check oop compression

```
java -Xmx32766m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2> /dev/null | grep UseCompressedOops
     bool UseCompressedOops                        := true                                {lp64_product}
```

for heaps larger than `32767m` JVM disables compressed oops:

```
java -Xmx32767m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2> /dev/null | grep UseCompressedOops
     bool UseCompressedOops                         = false                               {lp64_product}
```

Another option is to use diagostic vm options:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompressedOopsMode -version
```

which returns detailed information about oops mode:

```
heap address: 0x0000000082600000, size: 2010 MB, Compressed Oops mode: 32-bit
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000100000000 Req Addr: 0x0000000100000000
```

And the most advanced way is to use [HotSpot Serviceability Agent](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html) which allows to check more information about JVM internals:

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

public class OopsChecker extends Tool {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        VM vm = VM.getVM();
        System.out.println("CompressedOops = " + vm.isCompressedOopsEnabled());
        System.out.println("CompressedClassPointers = " + vm.isCompressedKlassPointersEnabled());
        System.out.println("OOP base = 0x" + Long.toHexString(vm.getDebugger().getNarrowOopBase()));
        System.out.println("OOP shift = " + vm.getDebugger().getNarrowOopShift());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OopsChecker().execute(args);
    }
}
```

You can play with heap size parameters and check output. The Java classes for SA are placed in `jdk/lib/sa-jdi.jar` so you have to add this jar into your classpath.

Comment: Thank your help @Ivan. I am going through the link and it is really very helpful.